# Book, tutorials or sources for creating rich/complex interface (android)

Tags: android

Pretty much the title. I'm new in android development. So, I'm interesting about developing rich application, but cannot find a good tutorials. I would be realy appreciated if someone guide me some resources for start.

Maybe there is some open source project where I can find helpful information?

Thank you

UPD1
Is there some guide from start to end where explained how to make an application such a twitter app? Or any other kind of complex and start to end described application?

Comment: http://www.muktware.com/distros/android, these people are just getting more and more into the tutorials

Comment: Thx for link. I'll be reading it :) But I guess this is not that I'm looking for. I updated post.

Comment: They say they will be getting into those kinds of things in the future. Will be good

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend starting here. The Google UI guidelines. It explains the different API for creating UI elements and also gets into pros/cons about icons, menus, fonts and so on.

http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Comment: Maybe I'm not saying clear... Of course I already looked at this. But I want to find something like a book or tutorial there will be explained HOW TO DO not HOW IT SHOULD be. For this purpose opensource project will be fine too. Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/sites/teach.appinventor.mit.edu/files/MIT%20App%20Inventor%20Development%20Overview_0.pdf

http://cs.usfca.edu/~wolber/appinventor/bookSplits/ch4NoTexting.pdf

These are some of the links that i found very useful for complex android app development.